# Did Andrei Tarkovsky ever explain what happens in the climax scene of the movie Solaris (1972)?

Tags: analysis, solaris-1972

Did the director ever explain his intentions for the ending of *Solaris (1972)*. Is the movie a paradox? Did he return to earth or remain stuck in the ocean? I need a very short and straightforward answer for this. I have already searched through all the articles available on the internet but have not been able to come to a conclusion.

Comment: The question title doesn't relate to the question description. Who is Andrei and what does he explain?

Comment: Also, why do you *need* a straightforward explanation? It's a complicated film made by a complicated filmmaker, explicitly dealing with illusion and reality. A short and straightforward conclusion would undermine what the film is trying to achieve.

Comment: @magarnicle We can apply what you said for any movie. But the director would have some ideas in his mind for the conclusion. I'm looking for that.

Comment: Can we? Does every film involve a planet that causes hallucinations? But if you want the *director's* interpretation then you should ask that more specifically in the question. If you want *my* interpretation - he never returned to earth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no idea why you couldn't relate question and description.

Comment: Because your title mentions 'Andrei', but then your description just asks 'what happened'? Who is 'Andrei' and why is his interpretation the correct one?

Comment: It is likely that the people most qualified to answer this question would also be the most offended by it.

Comment: In my humble opinion when it comes to Tarkovsky there are no straightforward answers. The best way to go forward is to watch the film again.